# Cannot understand how this Python code works

Tags: python, python-3.x, eval, args

I found this question on HackerRank and I am unable to understand the code(solution) that is displayed in the discussions page.

The question is:
Consider a list (list = []). You can perform the following commands:

insert i e: Insert integer  at position .
print: Print the list.
remove e: Delete the first occurrence of integer .
append e: Insert integer  at the end of the list.
sort: Sort the list.
pop: Pop the last element from the list.
reverse: Reverse the list.

Even though I have solved the problem using if-else, I do not understand how this code works:

```
n = input()
slist = []
for _ in range(n):
    s = input().split()
    cmd = s[0]
    args = s[1:]
    if cmd !="print":
        cmd += "("+ ",".join(args) +")"
        eval("slist."+cmd)
    else:
        print slist
```

Comment: I think you need to cast the variable n to an integer in order for this code snippet to work `n = int(input())`

Comment: this is not valid Python 3 code snippet

Answer (score 1):

It's dirty code that's abusing `eval`.

Basically, when you enter, for example, `"remove 1"`, it creates some code that looks like `sList.remove(1)`, then gives the created code to `eval`. This has Python interpret it.

This is probably the worst way you could solve this outside of coding competitions though. The use of `eval` is entirely unnecessary here.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the code takes advantage of Python's `eval` function. Many languages have this feature: `eval`, short for "evaluate", takes a piece of text and executes it as if it were part of the program instead of just a piece of data fed to the program. This line:

```
s = input().split()
```

reads a line of input from the user and splits it into words based on whitespace, so if you type "insert 1 2", `s` is set to the list `["insert","1","2"]`. That is then transformed by the following lines into `"insert(1,2)"`, which is then appended to `"slist."` and passed to `eval`, resulting in the method call `slist.insert(1,2)` being executed. So basically, this code is taking advantage of the fact that Python already has methods to perform the required functions, that even happen to have the same names used in the problem. All it has to do is take the name and arguments from an input line and transform them into Python syntax. (The `print` option is special-cased since there is no method `slist.print()`; for that case it uses the global command: `print slist`.)

In real-world code, you should almost never use `eval`; it is a very dangerous feature, since it allows users of your application to potentially cause it to run any code they want. It's certainly one of the easier features for hackers to use to break into things.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I Find some error in the code, but I came to an understanding of how this code runs. here is it:

input :

```
3
1 2 3
cmd = 1 + ( 2 + 3)
```

then `eval(cmd)` i.e., `eval("1 + (2 + 3)")` which gives an output 6
another input:

```
4 
4 5 6 2
cmd = 4 + ( 5 + 6 + 2)
eval(cmd)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    N = int(raw_input())
    lst=[]
    for _ in range(N):
        cmd, *line = input().split()
        ele= list(map(str,line))
        if cmd in dir(lst):
            exec('lst.'+cmd+'('+','.join(ele)+')')
        elif cmd == 'print':
            print(lst)
        else:
            print('wrong command', cmd)
```